# AngularJS & Bootstrap Modal - loading template outside controller

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I have a dialog which is being used in 3 scenarios within the same page.  I have created a controller similar to the below:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
  size: size,
  resolve: {
    items: function () {
      return $scope.items;
    }
  }
});


 <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Im a modal!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                <a ng-click="selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

The issue is, that since this dialog is being used in 3 different parts of the same page, I have a problem with the template.  When I put the html template outside of the controller, at the very end of the page html, it fails and gives me a 404.

However, I do not wish to repeat the same chunk of HTML in 3 places in the same page.  Can someone tell me if there's a different way of calling the template which is outside the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to reuse your template is to put it in a separate html file and put its url in `templateUrl`. So `$modal` can get it from server every time needed.

Comment: That would be the ideal scenario.  However the system I am working on minfies everything in 1 html file, so I was wondering whether I can have that html chunk in the script tag, somewhere at the bottom of the page, out of the controller so that it would be used in all the 3 cases.  

Is there a way to tell the controller to use that HTML chunk, which is outside of it but on the same page?

Comment: Ok, my fault! Did you put that template inside the `$rootElement`?

Comment: Thanks a lot!! that was my problem.  The template was residing outside of the $rootElement